# In Kubernetes, how can i have an access mode to allow one pod at a time to write and many pods to read only?

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, microservices

I tried to define a PVC:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: master-pvc
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
    - ReadOnlyMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

The nodes that need readonly access should define:

```yaml
volumeMounts:
- name: mastervol
  mountPath: /data/master/
  readOnly: true
```

The master that needs to read and write, should define:

```yaml
volumeMounts:
- name: mastervol
  mountPath: /data/master/
```

Is this a valid way to achieve what i want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a node that requests a `volumeMount`, but a container inside a Pod (many Pods may run in same node).

A PVC is 1-1 bound to a PV using a single access mode (even it supports many) at a time (see also [access modes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes)). So, you **cannot** have a PVC operating at the same time as `ReadWriteOnce` (for some Pods) and `ReadOnlyMany` (for some other Pods).

If you want to support 1 writer and many readers, one solution is to let them use a `ReadWriteOnce` volume and ensure that all Pods run on the same node the volume is mounted (e.g by using [node affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity) constraints).

Comment: what if i create a pv and pvc with readwritemany, one dedicated pod would writing and reset serving pods would only read, specifying readonly during container mount